# @RabbitListener - defining queues from properties

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp

Can a comma separated property be used to define the queues on which to listen?  The intent is to be able to change queue names and number of queues without code change.

I've defined queues in my `application.properties` like so:

```
my.aggregate.queues=/some/queue,/some/other/queue
```

I am able to include the queue names as lists by using [SpEL](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) as so:

```
@Value("#{'${my.aggregate.queues}'.split(',')}")
```

However, when I attempt to listen to the queues using the `@RabbitListener` annotation I find I must define the queues individually.  Using

```
@RabbitListener(queues = { "#{'${my.aggregate.queues}'.split(',')}" })
```

causes the queue names to be resolved to a string array, but not one capable of being used:

```
@RabbitListener can't resolve '[Ljava.lang.String;@5396eeb1' as either a String or a Queue
```

I've tried various other SpEL combinations without success.  Is there a way of using SpEL to dynamically define the queues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah; that SpEL will put an array of queue names in the first element of the `queues` array.

If you open a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP), there's a chance we can get a fix into the 1.5 release due next week.

I think we need to accept an expression that evaluates to a comma-delimited string and then do the split when processing the annotation.

**EDIT:**

However, I just realized that RabbitMQ allows you to create queues with commas in them, so maybe we should just handle the first array element itself being an array.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I'll open up an issue.  I've worked around it for now programmatically.  A way of specifying the array in the @RabbitListener annotation would certainly be preferable, and I agree with your conclusion in your edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Queue name in System variable "cluster.name", and need customize the name value with conditionals, you can use Spel:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "#{'${cluster.name}' != null?'batch.queue-${cluster.name}':'batch.queue'}", containerFactory = "listenerContainerFactory")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a programmatic workaround for the issue:

```
private MethodRabbitListenerEndpoint createEndpoint() {
  MethodRabbitListenerEndpoint endpoint = new MethodRabbitListenerEndpoint();

  endpoint.setQueueNames(queues.toArray(new String[] {})); // auto wired in
  endpoint.setAdmin(admin);
  endpoint.setBean(interceptor);
  endpoint.setId(ENDPOINT_ID);

  endpoint.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(createMethodFactory());

  endpoint.setMethod(ReflectionUtils.findMethod(MyInterceptor.class, “myMethod”,
      MyAbstractJsonSuperclass.class, Channel.class));

  SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = listenerFactory.createListenerContainer(endpoint);
  container.setupMessageListener(admin.getRabbitTemplate());

  return endpoint;
}

private MessageHandlerMethodFactory createMethodFactory() {
  DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory messageHandlerMethodFactory = new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory();

  messageHandlerMethodFactory.setMessageConverter(converter); // custom json converter
  messageHandlerMethodFactory.afterPropertiesSet();

  return messageHandlerMethodFactory;
}
```